# how to add user data to a model3d in helix3d toolkit

Tags: c#, wpf, helix-3d-toolkit

I can show 3d `GeometryModel3D` objects using Helix3d toolkit. Using `HitTest` I can select a particular object and show its tooltip. Is there anyway to attach the user data into 3d object when creating?

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own class inherit from GeometryModel3D. And add your custom properties in your own class.

Comment: Unfortunately They are sealed so we can inherit

Comment: Workaround is to use a Dictionary to find the user data from GeometryModel3D.